# Deserialize JSON for YARP config

Tags: c#, json, json.net, json-deserialization, ms-yarp

The following JSON is my request body:

```
{
    "Routes": {
        "route1": {
            "ClusterId": "cluster1",
            "Match": {
                "Path": "{**catch-all}",
                "Hosts": ["www.aaaaa.com", "www.bbbbb.com"]
            }
        }
    },
    "Clusters": {
        "cluster1": {
            "Destinations": {
                "cluster1/destination1": {
                    "Address": "https://example.com/"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to cast it as objects but it is not working

```cs
var reqItems1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Req>(jsonData);
```

Where `Req` is:

```cs
public class Req
{
    public RouteConfig Routes { get; set; }
    public ClusterConfig Clusters { get; set; }
}
```

`RouteConfig` and `ClusterConfig` are defined:

https://microsoft.github.io/reverse-proxy/api/Yarp.ReverseProxy.Configuration.RouteConfig.html

https://microsoft.github.io/reverse-proxy/api/Yarp.ReverseProxy.Configuration.ClusterConfig.html

Everything is null. How can I parse the request directly to objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the attached JSON, the `Routes` and `Clusters` properties are key-value pairs.

Hence your `Req` class should be as below:

```cs
public class Req
{
    public Dictionary<string, RouteConfig> Routes { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, ClusterConfig> Clusters { get; set; }
}
```